# Best way to handle Underlying Provider Failed to Open Internet Dropout

Tags: entity-framework, database-connection

What is the best way to handle internet dropouts with the entity framework? I have an app at a location that often has the internet die, and while it doesn't totally fall over, what are the strategies you have employed to wait for the internet to return - do we smash a while link, create a timer etc?

Comment: Can you please provide a little more context? Maybe some code as to what happens when you get a dropped connection? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For EF5 you can take a look at [SQL Azure and Entity Framework Connection Fault Handling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/12/11/sql-azure-and-entity-framework-connection-fault-handling.aspx) for some ideas . EF6 has a new feature - Connection Resiliency which allows database operations to be re-tried if the connection is lost. See [this](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Connection%20Resiliency%20Spec) for more details.